# How should a Qt-based preferences panel broadcast that a pref has changed?

Tags: qt

I am trying to design a preferences panel for my multidocument app.  When a given pref changes – font size, say – all of the document windows should immediately update to reflect the new pref value.  I don't want to construct the preferences panel up front, for all the document windows to connect to, because it contains a `QFontComboBox` that takes more than a second to set itself up (ouch); that's not a price I want to pay at startup.  So then, my question is: what is an elegant design for the prefs panel to let all the document windows know about the change?  In Cocoa, which I'm more used to, I'd use `NSNotification` to broadcast a notification from the prefs panel that all the document windows could observe; that provides the loose coupling required (since objects can add themselves as observers before the broadcaster exists).

Two approaches occur to me so far:

1. Loop through `topLevelWidgets`, do a dynamic cast to my document window class, and for all the document windows I thereby find, just call a hard-coded method on them directly.
2. Make a second class, `PreferencesNotifier`, that is separate from the UI object that takes so long to load, and construct a singleton object of this class at startup that all of the document windows can connect themselves to.  When the preferences panel eventually gets created, it can send signals to slots in `PreferencesNotifier`, which will then call its own signals to notify the connected document windows.

Neither seems quite as elegant as `NSNotification`, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, do not try to copy patterns, like Cocoa's `NSNotification`/`NotificationCenter`, to other frameworks (or languages, or...). There are various ways to send messages and generally each framework has picked one. Trying to use the one method that was picked by the framework you are using will lead to the most elegant solutions.

If you really want to, you could implement your own set of classes that will do exactly what `NSNotification` does. It will feel more elegant to you, but only because you are used to using Cocoa. It will feel odd to every other Qt developer. Also, this solution will require you to write a lot of code as you will not be able to leverage all the features of Qt.

The first solution you are suggesting is a bit ugly and looks more like a hack than anything.

What I do, when I have to handle preferences in a program, is something similar to your solution 2. I create a class that is responsible for handling all settings: read/write setting file, change setting, set default values, etc. Generally this class is a singleton. This class has very limited access to other parts of the program, and generally no access at all to the UI. Each components that needs to access the preferences will use this class. If you do it properly (e.g. use `Q_PROPERTY`), this class can even be accessed by QML, if you ever need to use Qt Quick.

```
class Settings: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROERTY(bool showX READ showX WRITE setShowX NOTIFY showXChanged)
public:
    bool showX() const { return m_showX; }
    void setShowX(bool show) {
        if (show == m_showX)
            return;

        m_showX = show;
        emit showXChanged(m_showX);
    }

signals:
    void showXChanged(bool);

public slots:
    void save() const; // Save to disk
    void load(); // Load from disk

private:
    QSettings m_settings; // Handle load/save from/to disk
    bool m_showX;
};

class Window {

    Window() {
        ...
        m_widgetX->setVisible(settings->showX());
        connect(settings, &Settings::showXChanged,
                this, [this](bool show) { m_widgetX->setVisible(show); }
                );
        ...
    }
};

class PrefWindow {

    PrefWindow () {
        ...
        ui->checkBoxShowX->setChecked(settings->showX());
        ...
    }

private slots:
    void on_saveButton_clicked() {
        settings->setShowX(ui->checkBoxShowX->checked()):
        settings->save();
    }
};
```

Comment: The lecture was not necessary; the whole point of my question was to ask what the idiomatic way of doing this in Qt would be, not to ask how to reimplement NSNotificationCenter in Qt.  :->  But thank you for the rest of your answer, which is helpful.  Cheers.